# Itunes Library main vs shared

Tags: itunes, macos

I recently moved by itunes library from my pc to an external hard drive and updated to itunes 11.0.  After doing this, when I click on my music I can see two separate libraries.  One is just under Library as music.  Then there is a second one listed below that says Shared Library and refers to the external hard drive.  Some of the songs from albums are missing in the main libary but are present on the Shared Library.   Do I need both of these libraries and if so is there a way to update the main library to get these missing songs from the shared library?

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is what I would recommend.Follow the steps:

- Clear Out your iTunes Library completely
- Copy the contents from your hard disk to a place on your Computer
- Add the folder from your computer to your iTunes Library and you will get back your old  arrangement of songs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how or why you want two libraries, but you can switch between both by quitting iTunes and holding the Shift (PC) or Option (Mac) key.

- [HT1589 - How to open an alternate iTunes Library file or create a new one](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1589)

Then you can export the playlists and everything about the library to your desktop as FileA.xml. Quit and repeat for the other library and make FileB.xml. Then you can choose to merge or not the files and songs / make your one library be the one you like and then import the two xml files to recreate whatever playlists you are missing. It's far easier to clean things up and have one library (a folder with all the iTunes database files) sitting in your user home folder and either store all the media there or store all the media on an external drive. Once you understand how to export the playlists and settings, it's much easier to change storage plans.